# Android - AnimationSet not working when combining TranslateAnimation

Tags: android, android-animation

I can't combine two TranslateAnimations, but if i run each animation separatly I have the expected results (works fine). My only problem is when trying to combine both TranslateAnimations in one AnimationSet, in this case no animation is rendered, and after the 4000 ms the image is rendered on top left of the parent view.

This is how I am trying to run both animations in a set:

```
private void animateView(int width, int height, View view) {
    AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    int startX1 = -(width / 2);
    int startY1 = getView().getHeight();

    int endX1 = getView().getWidth() / 3;
    int endY1 = getView().getHeight() - (getView().getHeight() / 3);

    int endX2 = getView().getWidth() - width / 2;
    int endY2 = 0;

    TranslateAnimation anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(startX1, endX1, startY1, endY1);
    anim1.setDuration(2000);
    animationSet.addAnimation(anim1);

    TranslateAnimation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(endX1, endX2, endY1, endY2);
    anim2.setDuration(2000);
    anim2.setStartOffset(2000);
    animationSet.addAnimation(anim2);

    view.startAnimation(animationSet);
}
```

Comment: instead animations (old-school) use animators (new-school): `ObjectAnimator` /  `ValueAnimator`

Comment: ^^Which can be combined using an `AnimatorSet`.